# How do I find out what items belong in which groups?

Tags: atelier-meruru-apprentice-of-arland

I noticed that items fall into certain categories (e.g. Tar Fruit is Fuel). Say, for example, I want to search for all (Ore) items. Is  there anywhere I can look that lists all (or as many items as possible) by group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to perform this action in-game. You can currently look through each item separately and the Library lists all groups that that item belongs to, but there is no way to look at all the items that belong to a certain group in-game.